# unexpected character after line continuation character when opening file in command line

Tags: python, syntax-error, newline

I have just started learning python and make a python file called "helloworld.py" and store it inside a  file called "python py" on the desktop, but this keep poping out whenever I am trying to open it in command line like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You're running a windows shell command in the Python shell. Run it directly in CMD instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a python shell (we can see that from `>>>`). Try starting cmd.exe and then run your same command:

```
python helloworld.py
```

(from the same path as the helloworld.py file).

When you run Python.exe (as you did), you can not run scripts. This is just for running commands "live". In your shell, try for example `print(1)`. It should work.